# Do browsers try to re-download the files which was skipped due it internet unavailability for few seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, browser

If a user is opening a website which is using jquery and some jquery plugins. when page assets being downloaded and internet connection goes down at the time when jquery library was being download. and if internet comes back after that, will browser try to re-download the jquery library?

Though I think browser will not try to access the file the again but I want to know what other developers think on it.

Answer (score 0):

No.   As far as I know there is no "auto-retry" mechanism for static resources.